# What should be done in case of pasting big error log and it asks to write more details?

Tags: discussion, bug, quality-filter

I posted a question recently, about some error log. I detailed all the steps and copied the error log. The editor wouldn't let me post as it was asking for more details.

I ended up writing some irrelevant stuff, which is not a nice thing to do of course. What should I do in cases where I put in enough details, but the error log is just too big?

Here is the question, I talk about: *[Install StrongLoop pm on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54495349/1)*.

And the funny thing, here is a similar question. With just one line detail and much bigger error log: *[Cannot install StrongLoop with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183904/cannot-install-strongloop-with-npm)*

Maybe this is even a bug?

Comment: Note: Jamming, "Here are more details" into the end of your post to bypass the quality filter is a *very* strong indicator that your post won't survive long enough for you get any answer; it'll just get closed and deleted.

Comment: @fbueckert yes, hence comes the question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no bug. Users are subjected to different strictness levels in the quality filter. Users with more than 2k reputation and full edit privileges encounter a more relaxed quality filter when publishing or editing posts.

In your specific case, instead of trying to bypass the filter by posting irrelevant noise, you should have spent more time thinking and or researching about any other real **real** details that could help someone to give you a better answer.

The system was trying to steer you into making a better question. In situations like these it pays to be humble and take the advise.

Comment: I accept the answer in sense that there was better solution rather than meaningless words. Maybe like posting some version numbers etc, that are irrelevant but may be relevant.

Comment: The reputation and quality filter the way you describe is kinda strange, so basically one is welcome to post "bad quality questions" if they have enough reputation.

Comment: And even though it doesn't matter now, but thanks for editing the question.

Comment: I think it's that users who have amassed large amounts of reputation are expected to be better judges of their post quality. Ultimately, it doesn't help them out in the long run because I doubt most people who downvote stop to consider, "Hey, this guy has more rep than me, maybe I shouldn't annoy him by downvoting."